# .net core 2.1:Angular SPA Template error : The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 50 sec

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have upgraded the .net core SPA template and migrated application to angular 6.

Following are the key settings in startup.cs file :

```
 app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

But while running the application i am always getting mentioned error in title.

> I have tried increasing the default time out for CLI but it wont help.

Comment: Have you try to increase the value of StartTimeout?  For instance:          `spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1, seconds: 30);` Adjust to your needs.

Comment: @abestrad Yes after adding TimeSpan got the same error but the only thing changed is value of seconds in error title : System.TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 30 second

Comment: whatever timing i set does not matter, it gives the timeout exception

Comment: hmm. I haven't tried because it worked for me. But, some have solved it by reinstalling the NuGet Project Templates.  `Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates` using your version obviously.

Comment: ok Thank You !!!

Comment: Have you invoked `npm install` before starting to debug the process ?

Comment: Yes i have performed the npm install

Comment: same issue occurred again

Comment: Navigate to ClientApp folder then run ng serve to see if there is any error

Answer (score 2):

**Above issue is due to the either dependencies are not present or CLI process taking time to listen for request. Follow below steps for solution:**

**First update the dependencies :**

Install @angular-devkit/build-angular as dev dependency.

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

or,

yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev

**Second Configure the timeout to 5 minutes to avoid "The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 50 seconds in startup.cs." issue**

spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);